# How to insert text anchor inside attributes onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery tab and it's working fine.
[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bxdm9cwo/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nnntabs ul a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var current = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.tab-content > div' + current).fadeIn('slow').show().siblings().hide();
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I just wanted to add more feature. The text anchor should be dynamically inserted inside the href and id attributes to activate the tab, or maybe replaced if there is a default value... The source of the value of href and id will be the text anchor of the menu. My fiddle sample is working fine because I inserted the values manually. Please help me turn this into reality... Thank you.[image: Image here]

Comment: No explanation for the downvote?

Comment: Hi, don't know who downvoted it.. but i wanna help & m not clear with ur exact requirement

Comment: can u explain in a single statement

Comment: As you can see on the image, the tab1 text anchor will go inside href, and id at the same time, onclick. same with other menu as well...

Comment: My fiddle sample is working fine because the value is already inserted manually.

Comment: Dear @user3892090, onclick of what? bcuz `<a>` tag must be already there with text... and u are not creating anchor tag dynamically

Comment: My text anchor will be manually added, and it should be dynamically inserted inside href and id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72628/discussion-between-victor-and-user3892090).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $content = $('.nnntabs > .tab-content > div');
  $('.nnntabs > ul a').each(function(i) {
    $(this).data('tab', 'tab-' + i);
    $content.eq(i).attr('id', 'tab-' + i)
  })

  $('.nnntabs ul a').on('click', function(e) {
    var current = $(this).data('tab');
    $('#' + current).fadeIn('slow').show().siblings().hide();
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.nnntabs {
  width: 100%;
}
.nnntabs ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nnntabs ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 0
}
.nnntabs ul li a {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  background: #eee;
}
.nnntabs ul li.active > a {
  background: #fff;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
}
.tab-content {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.tab-content > div {
  display: none;
}
.tab-content > .active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nnntabs">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tab3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="active">
      content1
    </div>
    <div>
      content2
    </div> 
    <div>
      cotent3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```